# Symfony2 : Where to place code running for all routes?

Tags: symfony

I need to run some code, for example, to detect browser prefered languages and set locale accordingly with available languages in my app and other things like that. This code will live inside a core bundle of my own.

I'm wondering where is the best place for this kind of code, let's say a sort of controller action that must run before any other.

I guess that making an include to the same file in both `app.php` and `app_dev.php` is a bad workaround, especially upon Symfony upgrades.

I can't find any answer in the docs nor on the web at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a listener for an [event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events). In most cases, `kernel.request` is what you need to listen for. I put listener classes into the `Listener` namespace of a bundle.

Comment: According to your answer, I finally found a [short example][1] from SF cookbook that does the job. Thanks again :-)


  [1]: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/request/mime_type.html

Answer (score 0):

But be careful — according to Sf2 docs (from your link):

> At any time during the handling of a request (the “master” one), a sub-request can be handled. You can pass the request type to the `handle()` method (its second argument)...